# How to scale each element in a matrix using conditional

Tags: r

I have an `m x n` matrix with values ranging from `-10` to `10`. I would like to do the following, but was wondering if there is a simpler way using the `ifelse()` command, or another one which can be applied to the whole matrix.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(mat)) {
        if (mat[i,j] > 0) {
            mat[i,j] <- 2^(mat[i,j])
        } else
            mat[i,j] <- (-1)*2^(mat[i,j])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifelse()` as you suggested:

```
set.seed(42)

mat <- matrix(runif(50, -10, 10), 5, 10)

mat1 <- 2^mat * ifelse(mat > 0, 1, -1)

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(mat)) {
    if (mat[i,j] > 0) {
      mat[i,j] <- 2^(mat[i,j])
    } else {
      mat[i,j] <- (-1)*2^(mat[i,j])
    }
  }
}

all.equal(mat1, mat)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice one.  You could cut down the calculations/code with `2^mat * ifelse(mat > 0, 1, -1)`

Comment: @RichardScriven  Right, I didn't check this part of the algorithm. Feel free to edit.

Comment: That's the command I had, I went back and realized I was using the wrong matrix in the `ifelse` which explains why I was getting the wrong values and didn't think it worked.

Comment: @TomNash  Then I don't feel comfortable to earn reputation with something you got, except the incorrect matrix.